# Error with React Native while using the StyleSheet component

Tags: react-native

So I am trying to develop a basic application in react native and this error keeps coming in

```
const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
          ^
    margin: 50
  }
})
```

the documentation says to do the exact same thing but it doesnt work.

( I imported it )

Comment: Can update your question with more information about what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Just pasting a sample code here since your code is not clear and complete. I hope you can map this implementation to yours and find the area which is causing the issue

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Modal } from 'react-native'
import AnimatedEllipsis from './AnimatedEllipsis'
import { Fonts } from 'theme'
import { Strings } from 'constant'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalBackground: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  activityIndicatorWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    height: 40,
    width: 124,
    borderRadius: 8,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  text: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  ellipsis: {
    color: 'white',
  },
})

const Loader = (props) => {
  const { loading, text } = props
  return (
    <Modal transparent={true} visible={loading}>
      <View style={styles.modalBackground}>
        <View style={styles.activityIndicatorWrapper}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
          <AnimatedEllipsis numberOfDots={3} animationDelay={100} style={styles.ellipsis} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  )
}

Loader.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  text: PropTypes.string,
}

Loader.defaultProps = {
  text: Strings.please_wait,
}

export default Loader
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import the StyleSheet before using it.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native'

const App = () => {
  return <View style={styles.container}><Text>Test</Text><View>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    margin: 50
  }
})
```